# Why are Firebase message ids in different format?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

We are using Firebase to send push notifications to mobile devices. Currently we want to resolve an issue when some notifications are not received, but are correctly sent with no firebase error.
After checking our logs, we noticed that when the notification was not received, firebase returns strange message id in response:
id for received notification: `projects/{our-project}/messages/1610712776892734`
id for lost notification: `projects/{our-project}/messages/0:1610453737216336%e29f3a03e29f3a03`

So my question is this - How does the different id format impact push notification deliverability?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm on the same boat now :(